# Once the first selection done then cursor should start to click the second one but if i give focus () is not working for select element type

Tags: triggers, click, focus

Am selecting the fist select option then once value changes cursor should move to next select field but for other input or text area focus() function working.
`<select type="text" class="form-select form-control-sm "id=“select_opt1” name="" placeholder="" required>`
`<option value="">Select</option>`
 `<option value="option1">option1</option>`
 `<option value="option2">option2</option>`
`<option value="option3">option3/option>`
`</select>`
`<select type="text" class="form-select form-control-sm "  id=“select_opt2” name="" placeholder="" required>`
`<option value="">Select</option>` option1  option2  option3   function movetonex(){ $('#select_opt2').focus(); } `
which method is useful to focus the second select element field.